# Flutter StreamBuilder is not working with buttons

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I am fetching data from my firebase real-time database and comparing values. If the values match is found, it is navigated to the next page. All of these elements are present in the StreamBuilder
pls fix my code. on the page when the button has pressed an action takes place based on the logic When the value on firebase is changed then the onpressed action takes place even though the button is not repressed pressed. Pls help

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool press;
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _getColor,
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              return StreamBuilder<List<MaterialStateProperty<Color>>>(
                  stream: findColors(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    press = false;
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Scaffold(
                          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(200, 8, 111, 118),
                          appBar: AppBar(
                            title: const Text(
                              "Home Layout",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            centerTitle: false,
                            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(200, 1, 47, 52),
                          ),
                          body: Center(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Flexible(
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Container(),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Container(
                                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: Column(children: [
                                                  const Text(
                                                    "This is the Home Parking Layout",
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      fontFamily: 'Oswald',
                                                      fontSize: 40,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    height: 20,
                                                  ),
                                                  Row(
                                                    children: [
                                                      Container(
                                                        width: 50,
                                                        height: 30,
                                                        decoration:
                                                            const BoxDecoration(
                                                          // border: Border.all(width: 2),
                                                          shape:
                                                              BoxShape.circle,

                                                          // You can use like this way or like the below line
                                                          //borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                                          color: Colors.red,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      const Text(
                                                        ' = Parking is occupied',
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.white,
                                                          fontFamily:
                                                              'Montserrat',
                                                          fontSize: 25,
                                                        ),
                                                      )
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    height: 5,
                                                  ),
                                                  Row(
                                                    children: [
                                                      Container(
                                                        width: 50,
                                                        height: 30,
                                                        decoration:
                                                            const BoxDecoration(
                                                          // border: Border.all(width: 2),
                                                          shape:
                                                              BoxShape.circle,

                                                          // You can use like this way or like the below line
                                                          //borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                                          color: Colors.blue,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      const Text(
                                                        ' = Parking is available',
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.white,
                                                          fontFamily:
                                                              'Montserrat',
                                                          fontSize: 25,
                                                        ),
                                                      )
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    height: 5,
                                                  ),
                                                  Row(
                                                    children: [
                                                      Container(
                                                        width: 50,
                                                        height: 30,
                                                        decoration:
                                                            const BoxDecoration(
                                                          // border: Border.all(width: 2),
                                                          shape:
                                                              BoxShape.circle,

                                                          // You can use like this way or like the below line
                                                          //borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                                          color: Colors.purple,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      const Text(
                                                        ' = Parking is booked',
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.white,
                                                          fontFamily:
                                                              'Montserrat',
                                                          fontSize: 25,
                                                        ),
                                                      )
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    height: 20,
                                                  ),
                                                  Row(
                                                    children: [
                                                      OutlinedButton(
                                                        onPressed: () async {
                                                          press = true;
                                                          DatabaseReference
                                                              ref =
                                                              FirebaseDatabase
                                                                  .instance
                                                                  .ref(
                                                                      'TimelessParking/P1');
                                                          ref.onValue.listen(
                                                              (DatabaseEvent
                                                                  event) {
                                                            if (event.snapshot
                                                                        .value ==
                                                                    0 &&
                                                                press) {
                                                              Navigator.push(
                                                                  context,
                                                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                                                      builder:
                                                                          (context) {
                                                                return const Parking1();
                                                              }));
                                                            } else {
                                                              showDialog(
                                                                  context:
                                                                      context,
                                                                  builder:
                                                                      (context) =>
                                                                          const AlertDialog(
                                                                            title:
                                                                                Text('Sorry! This parking cannot be booked'),
                                                                          ));
                                                            }
                                                          });
                                                        },
                                                        style: ButtonStyle(
                                                            backgroundColor:
                                                                snapshot
                                                                    .data![0]),
                                                        child: const Text(
                                                          'Parking 1',
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Colors.white,
                                                            fontFamily:
                                                                'Oswald',
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight.bold,
                                                            fontSize: 30,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      const SizedBox(
                                                        width: 45,
                                                      ),
                                                      OutlinedButton(
                                                        onPressed: () {
                                                          press = true;
                                                          DatabaseReference
                                                              ref =
                                                              FirebaseDatabase
                                                                  .instance
                                                                  .ref(
                                                                      'TimelessParking/P2');
                                                          ref.onValue.listen(
                                                              (DatabaseEvent
                                                                  event) {
                                                            if (event.snapshot
                                                                        .value ==
                                                                    0 &&
                                                                press) {
                                                              Navigator.push(
                                                                  context,
                                                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                                                      builder:
                                                                          (context) {
                                                                return const Parking2();
                                                              }));
                                                            }
                                                          });
                                                        },
                                                        style: ButtonStyle(
                                                            backgroundColor:
                                                                snapshot
                                                                    .data![1]),
                                                        child: const Text(
                                                          'Parking 2',
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Colors.white,
                                                            fontFamily:
                                                                'Oswald',
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight.bold,
                                                            fontSize: 30,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    height: 50,
                                                  ),
                                                  Row(
                                                    children: [
                                                      OutlinedButton(
                                                        onPressed: () {
                                                          press = true;
                                                          DatabaseReference
                                                              ref =
                                                              FirebaseDatabase
                                                                  .instance
                                                                  .ref(
                                                                      'TimelessParking/P3');
                                                          ref.onValue.listen(
                                                              (DatabaseEvent
                                                                  event) {
                                                            if (event.snapshot
                                                                        .value ==
                                                                    0 &&
                                                                press) {
                                                              Navigator.push(
                                                                  context,
                                                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                                                      builder:
                                                                          (context) {
                                                                return const Parking3();
                                                              }));
                                                            }
                                                          });
                                                        },
                                                        style: ButtonStyle(
                                                            backgroundColor:
                                                                snapshot
                                                                    .data![2]),
                                                        child: const Text(
                                                          'Parking 3',
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Colors.white,
                                                            fontFamily:
                                                                'Oswald',
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight.bold,
                                                            fontSize: 30,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      const SizedBox(
                                                        width: 45,
                                                      ),
                                                      OutlinedButton(
                                                        onPressed: () {
                                                          press = true;
                                                          DatabaseReference
                                                              ref =
                                                              FirebaseDatabase
                                                                  .instance
                                                                  .ref(
                                                                      'TimelessParking/P4');
                                                          ref.onValue.listen(
                                                              (DatabaseEvent
                                                                  event) {
                                                            if (event.snapshot
                                                                        .value ==
                                                                    0 &&
                                                                press) {
                                                              Navigator.push(
                                                                  context,
                                                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                                                      builder:
                                                                          (context) {
                                                                return const Parking4();
                                                              }));
                                                            }
                                                          });
                                                        },
                                                        style: ButtonStyle(
                                                            backgroundColor:
                                                                snapshot
                                                                    .data![3]),
                                                        child: const Text(
                                                          'Parking 4',
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Colors.white,
                                                            fontFamily:
                                                                'Oswald',
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight.bold,
                                                            fontSize: 30,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ]),
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ));
                    } else {
                      return Scaffold();
                    }
                  });
            default:
              return Scaffold();
          }
        }));
  }
}
```

I am expecting to open certain dialog boxes or pages only when the button is clicked but it happens automatically when the steam rebuilds.

Comment: your code is too long.Please only  paste the relevant code.

Comment: you can try `onPressed: () async {
                                                          final ref =
                                                              await FirebaseDatabase
                                                                  .instance
                                                                  .ref(
                                                                      'TimelessParking/P3')
                                                                  .get();

                                                          if (ref.value == 0) {}`